# What is "update classpath" mean in Java or SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, classpath

I'm reading the [Spring boot reference guide about the developer tools](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart), and it mentions the following:

> As DevTools monitors classpath resources, **the only way to trigger a restart is to update the classpath**. The way in which you cause the classpath to be updated depends on the IDE that you are using. In Eclipse, saving a modified file will cause the classpath to be updated and trigger a restart. **In IntelliJ IDEA, building the project (`Build → Make Project`)** will have the same effect.

I'm confused, what does "update the classpath" mean? More precisely:

- If I modify a file within my IDE, it doesn't appear to update the classpath, is this correct?
- If I click "Build" in IntelliJ, it does appear to update the classpath, but what exactly did the IDE just do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, the classpath specifies the location (path) of user defined classes in a project. Normally, a Spring Boot application needs be be manually restarted when changing a class (a file) to see the changes in action.

As you mentioned, the `spring-boot-devtools` provide an *[Automatic Restart](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html)*:

> Applications that use spring-boot-devtools automatically restart whenever files on the classpath change. This can be a useful feature when working in an IDE, as it gives a very fast feedback loop for code changes. By default, any entry on the classpath that points to a folder is monitored for changes. Note that certain resources, such as static assets and view templates, do not need to restart the application.
>
> As DevTools monitors classpath resources, the only way to trigger a restart is to update the classpath. The way in which you cause the classpath to be updated depends on the IDE that you are using. In Eclipse, saving a modified file causes the classpath to be updated and triggers a restart. In IntelliJ IDEA, building the project (Build -> Build Project) has the same effect.

Meaning, with IntelliJ, when building the project (and thereby updating the classpath), the dev-tools will trigger a restart of the application. More easily, one can also set IntelliJ to build automatically and activate `compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running` ([here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35895848/1901400)).